# Why does Rayleigh-Jeans law agree with Planck's at long wavelengths?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, thermal-radiation, wavelength, approximations

Why does Rayleigh-Jeans law agree with the Plancks distribution at high wavelengths? I know mathematically, that at higher wavelengths, we can approximate the exponential in the denominator by $1+ \frac{hc}{\lambda k_bT}$ which gives back the Rayleigh's law, but I do not understand what is the Physics behind this. Why does the classical result agree at high wavelength, i.e. low energy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Planck's postulate is, an electromagnetic oscilllator mode of frequency
$\nu$ can only have energies of $E=nh\nu$ (with $n=0,1,2,3,\dots$).
That means you have ladder-like energy levels, with small steps
at low frequencies, and big steps at high frequencies.
You can visualize these energie levels for some example frequencies $\nu$
and by how many oscillators they are occupied:

[image: energy levels with percentages]
<sub>(image from [my answer to another related question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/505136/black-body-radiation-curve/505385#505385))</sub>

Doing the math, Planck derived the average energy of an oscillator mode
at temperature $T$ to be
$$E_\text{avg}(\nu,T)=\frac{h\nu}{e^{h\nu/kT}+1} \tag{1}$$

And now ansering your question:
At the left part of the image above (i.e. for low frequencies $\nu$,
or equivalently for long wavelengths $\lambda$),
the fine-grained energy levels can be well approximated by an energy
continuum.

[image]

This leaves the distribution of the oscillators among the energy levels,
and hence the average energy nearly unchanged.
$$E_\text{avg}(T) \approx kT. \tag{2}$$
You can derive this average either directly from Boltzmann's distribution
(like Rayleigh-Jeans did) or as an approximation of (1) for $h\nu \ll kT$.

Comment: Sir, exactly what I was looking for. Thankyou.  Just one thing I have to ask, in your answer to the related question you mentioned; you said that the distribution of the oscillators in the energy levels would be governed by MB statistics. But if this is quantum mechanics, shouldn't we use BE statistics?

Comment: @Shikhar To get the probability that the oscillator of frequency $\nu$ has energy $E_n=nh\nu$) you use the Boltzmann distribution: $p_n\propto \exp(-E_n/kT)$.
See [The Derivation of the Planck Formula](https://edisciplinas.usp.br/pluginfile.php/48089/course/section/16461/qsp_chapter10-plank.pdf) (page 9).
This is conceptually different from asking how many photons have an energy between $E$ and $E+dE$. There you use the Bose-Einstein distribution.